# Is pointwise limit of random variable a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, sequence-of-function

Is pointwise limit of random variable is random variable?

Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is a complete measure space
and $V$ is a real separable Hilbert space with $\mathcal{B}(V)$ as its Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $f_n:\Omega\to V$  be a sequence of random variables. Suppose that there exists
$f:\Omega\to V$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(\omega) = f(\omega)$$ for almost all $\omega$, where the limit w.r.t induced norm $\Vert v \Vert =\sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle} $ in $V$.

Is $f$ a random variable?

Comment: Hint: $\{\omega: \|f(\omega)-x\| <r\}=\cup_k\cap_m\cup_{n \geq m} \{\omega: \|f_n(\omega)-x\| \leq r-\frac 1 k\}$.